# Mettre des accents français dans des fichiers - Put the french accents in HTML files (RoR)

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem with encoding. I want to add french accents in HTML files.
I'm on Ubuntu and my editor is SciTE.
This is a Ruby on Rails program.

ActionView::WrongEncodingError in Look#input

Your template was not saved as valid UTF-8. Please either specify UTF-8 as the
encoding for your template in your text editor, or mark the template with its
encoding by inserting the following as the first line of the template:

## encoding: .

The source of your template was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UFT-8"/>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset="utf8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <!-- ... autres mentions de l'ent&ecirc;te de fichier ... -->
</head>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Projet 3textfields, fichier input.rhtml</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Les champs de saisie (champs de texte) version 3</h1>
        <br>
        Cette application Ruby on Rails lit du texte saisi.
        <br>
        <br>
        Elle transmet la variable au mod�le.
        <br>
        <%= start_form_tag :action => 'at', :method => get %>
          Veuillez saisir votre nom.
          <br>
          <%= text_field "cruncher", "crunch",  :size => 30%>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="submit"/>
        <%= end_form_tag %>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`.  Note that you have `UFT-8`.

I am not familiar with SciTE.  Is it UTF-8 compatible?

Comment: I put this in a head of file

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <!-- ... autres mentions de l'entête de fichier ... -->
</head>

Answer (score 0):

May be it's related to utf-8 encoding not being recognised in ruby file (and by ActionView in that case). You may have to put this line at the top of each file containing non-ascii characters :

```
# encoding: utf-8
```